# PhpStorm 2016 and 2017 very slow for php projects on MacOS

Tags: performance, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1, phpstorm-2016.3

My PhpStorm 2016 start to slow down for php/js projects (laravel, angular, ionic).

First I try to change [JDK do JetBrains JDK](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207699905-2016-2-very-slow?page=1#comments) but this not help :(

Then I try to upgrade PhpStorm to 2017 - a little better but still not help (especially with php)

My CPU usage for PhpStorm is ~150%. It is very hard to use and work - what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accidently find answer when read article about [JVM options in PhpStorm](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) where in some comment one person put its config. So on my Mac in file (but first make backup copy):

`/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/phpstorm.vmoptions`

I replace below old content:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

With following new content:

```
-server
-Xss256k
-Xms1536m
-Xmx1536m
-Xmn512m
-XX:PermSize=350m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=350m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=350m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=0
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

And it works very smoothly now :) (CPU usage for PhpStorm is about ~15% now)